# Not able to use command net use to mount Azure File as drive on my Windows 8 PC

Tags: azure, azure-files

I have created an Azure File service and I am using the following command to mount it as a drive on my Windows 8 system:

```
net use * \\smb3share.file.core.windows.net\myfileshare /u:smb3share KEY
```

I have disabled firewall and turned off antivirus still I keep getting the following message from the command prompt:

> System Error 53 has occurred. The network path was not found.
>   [image: Error in command prompt]

Answer (score 1):

From documentation here:
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-files/

> File storage offers shared storage for applications using the standard
>   SMB 2.1 or SMB 3.0 protocol. Microsoft Azure virtual machines and
>   cloud services can share file data across application components via
>   mounted shares, and on-premises applications can access file data in a
>   share via the File storage API.

Azure File service is not intented to be used for On-Premises mounts (net use). For accessing files withing Azure File Service from **on-premise** computers/applications, you need to use the [Azure File Service REST API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn167006.aspx).

You can only mount Azure File Storage share from an Azure VM or Cloud Service.

**EDIT**

It seems that with the support for SMB 3.0, OS-es like Windows 8.0 / server 2012 and newer are also supported. Then, since you use Windows 8, then the only reason left is your ISP (Internet Service Provider) is blocking outgoing port 445, which is required by the SMB protocol. If you are doing this operation within corporate network (your workplace) the chance that everything outbound is blocked / filtered is much bigger.

Comment: Anton...this has changed. Now you can mound an Azure File Service Share from your local machine as well. Please see this link: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-files/#mount-the-file-share.

Comment: @astaykov I tried mounting the drive both from my corporate and home network and none worked. How can I diagnose the issue?

Comment: in both cases - call the support and ask if they explicitly block **outgoing** connections on TCP port 445.